# Metoer not running

Tags: meteor

I did the following:

```
meteor create simple-todos    
cd simple-todos
meteor --port 3030

    [[[[[ ~/simple-todos ]]]]]                    

    => Started proxy.                             
    => Started MongoDB.                           
    => Started your app.                          

    => App running at: http://localhost:3030/
```

But my browser at localhost:3030 doesn't show anything. Other than:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Any help would be super!

I'm on a Mac. Using meteor 1.3.2.4 (The current version)

I experience the same problem when running just the `meteor` command alone with no arguments.

I just noticed that my hostname is incorrect (name of a family member's ipad) I switched to a new hostname using the hostname command and set it to a new name (not my original) could this have something to do with issue?

Comment: [@Bren](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2848483/bren) Have you tried without the `--port 3030`?  Just run `meteor`.  What OS are you on?  Are you using an updated version of meteor?

Comment: @JeremyIglehart responded at the bottom of the post thanks!

Comment: If you do "cat /etc/hosts" what do you get? Do you have localhost pointing to 127.0.0.1. Can you try accessing 127.0.0.1:3030 directly?

Comment: I agree with Vijay - (and just tested this myself with my own meteor project) - Try opening the project using `http://127.0.0.1:3030/` - it works for me when I run `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` (I'm using the standard port).

Comment: @Vijay if you make your comment an answer ill accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my etc/hosts file (typo). If Vijay wants to post an answer I'll delete this and accept that.